# Python: binding (otherwise) undefined names to an object

Tags: python, namespaces, processing, replit

This question derives from a very specific use-case. Some clever person has put together a repl.it that allows you to use the Python version of the Processing libraries on the web:

https://repl.it/@templates/Python-Processing

The Python code looks like this:

```
from browser import document, window, alert

def sketch(p): 
  #this p is needed. it will be the processing sketch itself.
  # to do things like background(0) instead do p.background(0)

    def setup():
        p.createCanvas(700, 410)
        p.background(0)
        p.rectMode(p.CENTER)


    def draw():
        #p.background(0) 
        p.fill(255,255,0,128)
        p.ellipse(p.mouseX,p.mouseY,50,50)


    def mousePressed(self):
        p.background(0)


    def keyPressed(self):
      if p.key==" ":
        print("Hallo")


    p.setup = setup
    p.draw = draw
    p.mousePressed = mousePressed
    p.keyPressed = keyPressed

myp5 = window.p5.new(sketch)
```

The issue is that I'd really like the user code to just look like this (as it would in a desktop version of the Python version of Processing):

```
def setup():
    createCanvas(700, 410)
    background(0)
    rectMode(CENTER)


def draw():
    fill(255,255,0,128)
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50)


def mousePressed(self):
    background(0)


def keyPressed(self):
  if key==" ":
    print("Hallo")
```

...but as you can see in the repl, all of the calls have to be prefaced by "p." so that they are acting on the processing sketch, and wrapped in a function that takes that sketch as an argument.

I guess the question boils down to this: is there a way of wrapping things so that otherwise undefined global variables/functions (e.g. `createCanvas`) get bound to a particular object (in this case resolving to `p.createCanvas`)?

I recognize that it's kind of unpythonic, since it's about making implicit what was otherwise explicit, but in this case, it would serve to make the code more in the spirit of the Processing libraries.

Comment: Maybe you can use "exec" and create a dictionary-like object which provides the respective "p" attribute on demand and can be used as "locals".

Comment: Thanks for this -- it's a clever idea! I think it doesn't seem to work because of a quirk of how brython approaches dictionaries. But it should have worked!